# JSON value doesn't well formed in jquery autocomplete

Tags: java, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have problem with my jquery autocomplete script.
Here is my code:

back

```
<?php
require_once("include/global.php");
require_once("include/con_open.php");
$q = "select name, id from tbl_hotel";
$query = mysql_query($q);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $return = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$row["name"],'id'=>$row["id"]));
    }
}
echo(json_encode($return));
```

front

```
<input type="text" id="hotel" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn0.favehotels.com/v2/style/autocomplete/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">                     
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#hotel" ).autocomplete({
        position: { my : "right bottom", at: "right top" },
        source: "hotel-search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location.href=ui.item.id;
        }                   
    })._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append($("<a></a>").text(item.label))   
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
</script>
```

`source: "hotel-search.php"` returning `[{"label":"A", "id":"1"}]`

when I changet the line `source: "hotel-search.php"` to `source: [{"label":"A", "id":"1"}]`

it doesn't work yet.

but when i change it to `source: [{label:"A", id:"1"}]` it works fine.

what should I do to make return of "hotel-search.php" to be like `{label:"Hotel A", id:"1"}` not `{"label":"Hotel A", "id":"1"}`

Comment: If you question is in relation to how to modify the result returned from `hotel-search.php`, then you'll need to show us the code in that page, not the code from the requesting page.

Comment: `{label:"Hotel A"}` is not a valid JSON. I doubt that any library will allow you to make it like this. By the way: do you get any errors with standard JSON? What do you mean by `it doesn't work`?

Comment: When you say _"it doesn't work yet"_, what's the problem? Do you have any error?

Comment: "it doesn't work yet" refers the autocomplete keep showing up all list. It keep showing "A", even I typed "B"

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote
Look xhr response on demos...

Comment: You've messed up with something else. Look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rh3Gp/ It works just fine with JSON.

Comment: Aure77

In [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) descriptions was writed that:

Expected data format

The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:

An Array of Strings:
`[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
`[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

> Naufal Abu Sudais: "it doesn't work yet" refers the autocomplete keep showing up all list. It keep showing "A", even I typed "B"

When you use `autocomplete` with AJAX call, a GET parameter is sent to the service, **term** :

```
hotel-search.php?term=WhatYouTypeInAutocomplete
```

So if you want shortest list, You must use `$_GET['term']` in your PHP file to filter response items.

Comment: from start, it works when I use that. but if use that method, the autocomples need much time waiting the backend generating the queries first.

Comment: my problem is: what should I do to make return of "hotel-search.php" to be like `{label:"Hotel A", id:"1"}` not `{"label":"Hotel A", "id":"1"}`

Comment: See jquery demo and look for JSON response : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=corn

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.getJSON` to let jQuery to get and parse JSON response as JSON Object :

```
$.getJSON('hotel-search.php', function(jsonData) {
   $("#hotel" ).autocomplete({
        position: { my : "right bottom", at: "right top" },
        source: jsonData,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location.href=ui.item.id;
        }                   
    })._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append($("<a></a>").text(item.label))   
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```